# Getting data from database into json using php

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I can get data from database in this way;

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","demo"); 
$sql = "Select value From Users WHERE name in ('username', 'surname', 'age')"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){ 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo $row["value"]; 
    } 
} 
mysqli_close($con);
```

Output:

```
JohnWick42
```

How can I get this data in json

sample json output:

```
{"result":[{ 
    "username":"John", 
    "surname":"Wick", 
    "age":"42" 
    } 
]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could always use `json_encode` to encode the data in a json format

Comment: How can I do that? Can you help me?

Comment: I'm in php. I have created the above code very hard @Jaspa

Comment: Have you ever googled "php json"? The first result leads to the answer of @Samuel

Comment: How will you differentiate between 2 sets of data in this? 

For example, `JohnWick42` will be one set and let's say `JohnHarper27` is another. 

So, how will you differentiate between these 2 `during looping` through the rows? We can use some temporary variable but the code will not be elegant.

Comment: This SQL reads nonsensically.  `WHERE name IN ('John', 'Ringo', 'Paul') `, means return the rows where name is John, Ringo or Paul.

Comment: I solved the problem. thanks everyone

Comment: @Progrock Did you answer me? If yes, then I still don't get how he will differentiate values with proper mapping of respective keys with respective values?

Comment: @michaelzX Can you put more light on this? If you solved, can you post your answer and also show us how your table looks like with the data?